# storing strings in utf8 from microsoft word

Tags: utf-8, ms-word, character, pasting

I am working on a website that will allow businesses to store a description. The problem that I am currently running into is when text is copied and pasted from Microsoft word, and a few other places the strings are being returned, but not as the original characters. I do not have the best understanding of how utf8 works, but I thought that was supposed to handle this.

My question is this. Am I incorrect in thinking that utf8 will handle characters from word. If so, what is the proper way to accomplish this?

- We have

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  ```

  at the top of every page.
- Jave backend using spring as our framework
- ibatis to handle sql injection
- and mysql for the db

The characters are being changed over by the time they make it into the database and are being saved as the different character. I have done a decent amount of searching around and haven't come to a good conclusion why they are being changed. A few example characters being switched are:
From word
– changed to â
From a clients webiste
’ to â€™
‘ to â€˜

I would like to make it so that they will be able to copy from almost everywhere and it will format correctly. How would you recommend me doing that?

SOLVED!!
The problem ended up being an issue with my web.xml configuration. I was not forcing the web to use spring's utf8 configuration. The solution (if using spring) was as follows:

The problem ended up being a configuration problem with spring. Thank you for the help.
Spring configuration:

```
`<filter>
<filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>encoding</param-name>
<param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>`
```

Comment: When you copy text from Word, Word will put several different formats on the Windows clipboard (assuming we're talking about the Windows version of Word here). SOme of these formats are standard and have names, such as CF_TEXT, CF_UNICODETEXT etc. As far as I know, CF_UNICODETEXT is always 16-bit Unicode (the "Little-endian" type), not UTF-8. As long as whatever is getting the data from the clipboard knows that, it really ought to be able to deal with it correctly. If it is treating the characters as UTF-8, the outcome will be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would happen if you take text that has been converted to bytes using UTF8, then read tghe bytes using a single-byte ASCII encoding.

You need to find out where in your code that happens, and fix it to read the bytes as UTF8.